# 1 delegate to 3 view controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

I have a cameraViewController that is essentially a barcode scanner. I also have 3 view controllers (A, B and C) each with a button that lead to this cameraViewController.

When cameraViewController scans a barcode, it does the following:

```
if (self.detectionString != nil)
    {
        [self.delegate cameraViewController:self withCardNumber:self.detectionString];
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES ];

        break;
    }
```

It has a delegate and sends the detected string back to the previous/parent view controller. 
All three viewControllers have the following methodimplemented:

```
#pragma mark - CameraViewControllerDelegate

- (void)cameraViewController:(CameraViewController *)cameraViewController withCardNumber:(NSString *)number
{
self.CardNumbertext.text = number ;
}
```

So both methods work with cameraViewController and viewControllerA. However, when the parentViewController is B or C, the cameraViewController still pops back to the right controller but the delegate function does not run. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There can only be one delegate of an object at a time, so it appears that controller A is the one taking that roll. So you either need to have the previous delegate give up that roll so another can become the delegate, or use NSNotification instead.

Comment: How do you set up and switch the delegates?

Comment: At the time of initialisation of the cameraViewController, set the delegate as the "current" parentViewController.

Comment: You should show the code for how you set the delegate. Also explain your controller hierarchy (are A, B,and C embedded in a navigation controller, do you have a tab bar controller, etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Post a notification to `NSNotificationCenter`, it's a much better solution to this problem :)

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsnotificationcenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: why is that better? see my comment below, seems better if each VC owns its own instance and can release it when finished.

Comment: Your solution is also a good one, RobP. I suppose the decision rests with preference.

Answer (score 1):

It's iffy to have just one instance of cameraViewController and three different view controllers that "fight over it" by each setting the cameraVC's delegate to themselves. I think it's a better use of system resources and better architecture if each of the A, B, C viewcontrollers responds to the button press by instantiating a new instance of CameraViewController and setting that instance's delegate to self. This should fix your issue and improve memory management/leak issues as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want keep the current implementation then update the delegate when you are presenting ViewController A,B and C. From the way you described in the question seems like you need to do this in `-(void)viewWillAppear` or `-(void)viewDidAppear`. Or use the notification manager as the OP suggested or else use blocks.